# Opening VS solution in VS 2008 after it's already been opened in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have a Visual Studio project solution for a SSRS reporting service that must be opened in VS 2008 in order to function correctly, however I accidentally opened it from VS2010 and now cannot get the file to revert back due to something on my local box.  I have Deleted the solution folder and "gotten latest" from the server via the source controller (which I know has not yet been upgraded), however some clinging footprint is keeping it from reverting back and still references the .sln file as being a VS2010 and gives me the below error.  Any ideas?

"*.rptproj cannot be opened because it's project type is not supported by the application."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a surprising fix, the problem was being caused by a missing service pack on my SQL Server 2008 R2, after pushing that update, the VS 2008 is able to open the report solution no problem.